# Compute $\lim_{x\to0} (\sin x)^x$ using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits

Help me to compute this limit with L'Hospital's rule.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\sin x)^x$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the limit exist?

Comment: H Hospitals law limits need to solve this math

Comment: No need to comment on someone's grammar mistakes, especially when English are not they're first language.

Comment: L. hospitals law

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We need $x>0$, then use

$$ (\sin x)^x=e^{x \log \sin x}=e^{\frac{\log \sin x}{\frac1x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital's rule to complete the standard exercise of finding that
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$$
So we have that, as $x\to0$, $\sin x\sim x$. Now the limit you have becomes
$$L=\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)^x = \lim_{x\to 0}x^x = \lim_{x\to0}e^{x\ln x}.$$
Now, take the log of this limit and find $\ln L$. Once you've done that, just exponentiate this value to find $L$.